# yaml use $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH in script

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

In Yaml:
I have to create directory like: piblic/branch_name
-then copy there some.html
-then publish it in artifacts

```
GenerateSomeReport:
...
script:
- mkdir -p public/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
- cp -a some.html public/$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH/
rules:
- when: manual
artifacts:
  when: always
  paths:
    - public
```

What I do wrong? I do not see sub-folder in artifacts, but some.html placed in public/some.html

[image: Picture]

Comment: What kind of pipeline? `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is ‘_Available in branch pipelines, including pipelines for the default branch. Not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines._’

Comment: Yes, this pipeline is available for a branch

Comment: how to work with CI_COMMIT_BRANCH in script part?